# How to find concentration of a solution, differential equation problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A tank initially contains $100 \text{gal}$ of brine, a solution of salt and water, whose salt concentration is $0.5 \frac{\text{lb}}{\text{gal}}$. Brine whose salt concentration is $2 \frac{\text{lb}}{\text{gal}}$ flows into the tank at the rate of $3\frac{ \text{gal}}{ \text{min}}$. The mixture flows out at the rate of $2\frac{ \text{gal}}{ \text{min}}$. Assume the salt is uniformly distributed throughout the mixture. Find the salt concentration of the brine at the end of $30$ minutes.

Letting $x $ be the amount of salt at any time $t$
I got
$$
\frac{\text{dx}}{\text{dt}}=6-\frac{2x}{100+t}
$$ 
$$
x = \frac{6[10,000t+100t^2+\frac{t^3}{3}]}{(100+t)^2}
$$
What is the meaning of concentration of the brine? Is it $\frac{\text{dx}}{\text{dt}}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(NOTE: My first answer was wrong. This is a corrected answer.)

Concentration is the amount of solute (salt in this case) divided by the volume of the solution (brine in this case). So assuming that the unit of $x$, the amount of salt, is pounds, the concentration of the brine in the tank at the start is

$$\frac x{100}\frac{\text{lb}}{\text{gal}}$$

However, the volume in the tank does not remain at $100$ gallons. The inflow of liquid has the rate $3\frac{\text{lb}}{\text{gal}}$ while the outflow has the rate $2 \frac{\text{lb}}{\text{gal}}$, so the net inflow is $1 \frac{\text{lb}}{\text{gal}}$. So the volume of the tank at time $t$ is not $100$ but rather $100+t$.

Therefore the concentration of salt in the tank at time $t$ is

$$\frac x{100+t}\frac{\text{lb}}{\text{gal}}$$

Because of that, your differential equation is correct. The rate of flow of salt into the tank is $2 \frac{\text{lb}}{\text{gal}}\cdot 3\frac{ \text{gal}}{ \text{min}}=6\frac{\text{lb}}{\text{min}}$. The rate of flow of salt out of the tank is the concentration of the brine times the rate of flow out, namely $\frac{x}{100+t}\cdot 2\frac{ \text{lb}}{ \text{min}}$. Therefore, your equation is

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=6-\frac{2x}{100+t}$$

with the initial value

$$x(0)=100\cdot 0.5$$

How did you get the correct equation without understanding the concentration? Anyway, the meaning of $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is the rate of change of the mass of salt in the tank, not the concentration.

Comment: Ahh thanks. It just didn't click when I did it yesterday. Now I notice the concentration is just part of the initial setup of the problem! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Oh, yumyumyum, a brine tank problem! The first question was about concentration: this is the amount of solute per volume of solution, so here it is that $\frac x{100+t}$ that you already knew to put in the outflow term. @Rory Daulton is making the mistake of neglecting the changing volume of brine in the tank, @Jimmy Kudo is forgetting about the outflow from the tank, and @shoestringfries has the right differential equation, but is not integrating it properly. Let's copy that equation:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=6-\frac{2x}{100+t}$$
This is first-order linear, usually written as
$$\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac2{100+t}\cdot x=6$$
The integrating factor is
$$\mu=e^{\int\frac2{100+t}dt}=e^{2\ln(100+t)}=(100+t)^2$$
So
$$\frac d{dt}\left((100+t)^2x\right)=(100+t)^2\frac{dx}{dt}+2(100+t)x=6(100+t)^2$$
Integrating,
$$(100+t)^2x=2(100+t)^3+C$$
At $t=0$, $100^2(100)(0.5)=2(100)^3+C$, so $C=-\frac32(100)^3$.
Then at $t=30$,
$$\frac x{t+100}=2-\frac{\frac32(100)^3}{(130)^3}=\frac{2894}{2197}\,\,[lb/gal]$$

Comment: Yes, my first answer was wrong, as I realized when I was getting into bed last night, after I turned off my computer. +1 for you!

Comment: Did you mean $2x$ instead of $2$ in the numerator of the fraction in your second differential equation?

Comment: and where did your $6$ go after you multiplied everything by the integrating factor, in the equation after the word "integrating"?

Comment: @shoestringfries As for the $2x$ vs. $2$, that's a typo, gratefully acknowledged. Will be fixed. The $6$ went away because $$\int6(100+t)^2dt=6\cdot\frac13(100+t)^3+C=2(100+t)^2+C$$ When I took differential equations long ago, I was very lazy and never bought the textbook, never did any problems, and only went to class every week or so with the result that the only kind of problem I could solve was brine tank problems. But the professor was kind enough to put one such problem on every test so I passed anyway. Learned much more later studying on my own.

Comment: Same with me. invested 0 money and time in the course lol. the only kind of problems i did are these dilution problems xD

Answer (score 0):

Let $t$ be time in minutes
$$We\ know\ that,\qquad Concentration= \frac{amount\ of \ solute}{volume\ of\ solution}$$

---

$At \ t=0\min\\
Amount\ of\ brine=(0.5\frac{lb}{gal})(100 gal) =50lb
\\Amount\ of\ solution\ in\ tank=100gal$

---

$At\ time=t\ min
\\Amount\ of\ solute\ incoming=(2\frac{lb}{gal})(3\frac{gal}{min})t=6t\ lb
\\Volume\ of\ solution\ incoming\ in\ tank=3t\ gal
\\Amount\ of\ solute\ outgoing=\frac{(50+6t)(2t)}{100+3t}\ lb
\\Volume\ of\ solution\ outgoing=2t\ gal
\\Amount\ of\ solute\ remaining=\frac{(50+6t)(100+t)}{100+3t}\ lb
\\Volume\ of\ solution\ remaining=(100+t)\ gal$

---

$$Concentration\ of\ brine\ solution\ at\ time\ t\ minutes =\frac{50+6t}{100+3t}\frac{lb}{gal}
\\ At\ t=30\ minutes
\\Concentration\ of\ brine\ solution =230/190\frac{lb}{gal}$$
I hope that I didn't make any mistake, if you find any mistake, please comment or edit.
Question doesn't belong to mathematics, its from Mole Concept of Physical Chemistry

EDIT:- Explanation of amount of outgoing solute considering Concentration to be constant in whole process of out-coming of the solution
 $$Concentration\ of\ solution = \frac{50+6t}{100+3t} 
\\ Amount\ of\ solute\ outgoing=\frac{(50+6t)(2t)}{100+3t}
\\ Amount\ of\ solute\ remaining=1-\frac{(50+6t)(2t)}{100+3t}$$

Comment: How did you get "Volume of solute outgoing"? It seems that you did not take the volume of outgoing solution when forming that expression.

Comment: Thank you sir, I am very delighted to see comment of a great teacher. I think you are saying about "amount of solute outgoing" . I would like to say that that was the toughest thing I faced in the problem, because the question is not clear regarding solution's uniformity when the process is occurring ie if the Concentration in constant at that point of time or not. I am adding the explanation of that in the answer . thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Rory please see the changes :)