# chain rule in a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let's say there is a tank of brine, with 50kg of salt (call that $m$), and 1000l of brine at the beginning (call that $v$). There is incoming clean water to the tank at a speed of 1l/s. How would one make a differential equation of the system, for the change of mass of salt, per second: $\frac{dm}{dt}$?

If I think about it from a higher level, there is no change to the overall mass of salt in the tank, because only the clean water is entering, so $\frac{dm}{dt} = 0$.

However, as far as I can see, $\frac{dm}{dv} < 0$, because the density of salt is decreasing, and $\frac{dv}{dt} = 1$, because of the incoming clean water. Then, by chain rule we would have:

$\frac{dm}{dt} = \frac{dm}{dv} \cdot \frac{dv}{dt} < 0$

And that contradicts the initial $\frac{dm}{dt} = 0$. Do you know where I'm making a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mass $m$ is constant, regardless of whether it is viewed as a function of $t$ or of $v$, so $\frac{dm}{dv}=0$.

The thing which you want to say is negative is not the derivative of the **mass**, $\frac{dm}{dv}$, but the derivative of the **density**, $\frac{d(m/v)}{dv} = - \frac{m}{v^2}$.

Comment: Thanks! Mass is constant, but how can mass per unit of volume still be constant, when the density of salt is decreasing with time?

Comment: @S11n: Eh, what? I never claimed that $m/v$ is constant. On the contrary, it is obviously decreasing, which fits well with the fact that its derivative is negative.

Comment: Thanks! I was wrongly interchanging constant mass $m$ and mass as a function of volume of brine $m(v)$, which is probably a scaled density.

Comment: Is density defined to be $m/v$ or $dm/dv$? It seems like it is $m/v$, but I thought before it was the latter, like speed ($ds/dt$). I would appreciate if you could shed some light on that, too.

Comment: @S11n: Density is by definition $m/v$ (unit of mass per unit of volume). Mass $m$ is mass, regardless of whether you view it as a function of time, $m=m(t)$, or as a function of volume, $m=m(v)$. These functions have derivatives $dm/dt$ and $dm/dv$, which measure how quickly $m$ changes as $t$ or $v$ changes. (In this case both derivatives are zero, since $m$ doesn't change at all.) I have no idea what you might mean when you say that $m(v)$ is “probably a scaled density”.

Comment: Thanks! This discussion is very helpful for me! "probably a scaled density" probably was coming from my original misunderstanding that whenever we have $a/b$ as the metric (e.g. $m/s$ for speed), I thought we could use the rate of change to define that, but it looks like some quantities are defined statically (e.g. density) and some are rates of change (e.g. speed, or the rate of change of density with respect to changing the volume, which is different from density), so I was most probably wrong about that "scaled density".

Answer (score 1):

There are three variables which depend on $t$: the mass $m$, the volume $v$ and the density $s$.

They are related by $m=vs$.

So by the Chain Rule (correctly applied) we have

$$
\frac{dm}{dt}=\frac{\partial m}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dt}+\frac{\partial m}{\partial s}\frac{ds}{dt}=s\frac{dv}{dt}+v\frac{ds}{dt}.
$$

Now the volume increases as you say, but the density decreases, so there is no problem saying that $\frac{dm}{dt}=0$.

Comment: Thanks! Could the right hand-side of the first equality be reduced to $2\frac{dm}{dt}$? If yes, then I don't understand how could $\frac{dm}{dt} = 2 \frac{dm}{dt}$. If not, then I don't understand why it cannot be reduced to $2\frac{dm}{dt}$. Can you please expand on that?

Comment: I have no idea why you think that $2\frac{dm}{dt}$ has anything to do with what I have written. In this precise situation where $\frac{dm}{dt}$ is equal to $0$ then of course it is equal to $2\frac{dm}{dt}=0$; but that is the only way in which you can have that equality.

Comment: Thanks! Because $\frac{dm}{dv} \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dm}{dt} \land \frac{dm}{ds} \frac{ds}{dt} = \frac{dm}{dt} \implies \frac{dm}{dv} \frac{dv}{dt} +\frac{dm}{ds} \frac{ds}{dt} = 2 \frac{dm}{dt}$. Doesn't it hold in general?

Comment: In addition, it seems that the density is not $\frac{dm}{dv}$, but $\frac{m(t)}{v(t)}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722399/how-to-find-concentration-of-a-solution-differential-equation-problem

Comment: You are thoroughly confused about this. Look at it carefully: there are partial derivatives  involved and you are replacing them with one-dimensional derivatives and then applying a fake version of the Chain Rule. And nowhere have I said that the density is $\frac{dm}{dv}$.

Comment: You are completely right that I'm thoroughly confused about that. I don't know much about partial derivatives yet - they are supposed to be covered in the second volume of Tom Apostol's calculus, and I'm still at the first one. Overall I agree with your explanation, that one is negative and another one is positive, so they can cancel out, but unfortunately, as you noticed, I don't understand every step of your solution. How come the density is $\frac{\partial m}{\partial v}$?

Comment: I didn't say that the density was $\frac{\partial m}{\partial v}$. The density is $s$, and the rate of change of density is $\frac{ds}{dt}$. So we have that the RHS is $s$ times something positive ($\frac{dv}{dt}$) plus $v$ times something negative ($\frac{ds}{dt}$).

Comment: From your equation $\frac{\partial m}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dt}+\frac{\partial m}{\partial s}\frac{ds}{dt}=s\frac{dv}{dt}+v\frac{ds}{dt}$ doesn't it follow that $s = \frac{\partial m}{\partial  v}$? Because of derivative rule for a product, I understand the right most part of the equation, but not the middle one, where you added the partial derivatives.

Comment: One reads equations left-to-right. I know the first equation by the Chain Rule applied to the function $m(t)=m(v(t),s(t))$. I know the second because $m=vs$. Then $s\frac{dv}{dt}>0$ and $v\frac{ds}{dt}<0$ and indeed they cancel out.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense!