# A dilution problem (example $4$, Tom Apostol's Calculus vol $1$, section $8.6$)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The problem setup (from page $316$ in Tom Apostol's Calculus Vol $1$ book) is as follows. A tank contains $V = 100$ gallons of brine, whose concentration is $\rho(0) = 2.5$ pounds of salt per gallon. Brine containing $\rho_i = 2$ pounds of salt per gallon runs into the tank at speed $v_i = 5$ gallons per minute. The concentration of salt is kept uniform by steering, and the brine runs out at the same speed of $v_o = 5$ gallons per minute. What is the amount of salt in the tank at every instant in time.

The solution says that there are 2 components which change the amount of salt in the tank:

1. The incoming brine at 2 pounds per gallon, at speed 5 gallons per minute.
2. The running out brine at 5 gallons per minute.

From $1$, the rate of the salt amount change is $dy/dt = 10 \frac{lb}{min}$. From 2, the rate of salt amount change is $dy/dt = -y/20 \frac{lb}{min}$. From that the equation follows:

$y' = 10 - \frac{y}{20}$

But I am not sure how to go deeper into the derivation.

The concentration is defined as $\rho(t) = \frac{m(t)}{v(t)}$, instead of $\rho = \frac{dm}{dt}$ ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4490505/942378)), but I don't know how to look at the outgoing mass.

I would start like this:

1. Incoming mass: $m_i(t) = \rho_i v_i t$. The rate of change: $\frac{dm_i}{dt} = \rho_i v_i = 10$
2. Outgoing mass: $m_o(t) = \rho(t) v_o t = \frac{m(t)}{V} v_o t$. The rate of change: $\frac{dm_o}{dt} = \frac{v_o}{V} (m'(t) t + m(t)) = \frac{y' t}{20} - \frac{y}{20}$

Then the equation would be:

$y' = 10 - \frac{y' t}{20} - \frac{y}{20}$

Which is incorrect. I understand that the outgoing rate change should be $\rho(t) v_o = \frac{m(t) v_o}{V}$ ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722399/how-to-find-concentration-of-a-solution-differential-equation-problem)), but I'm not sure how to derive that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your outgoing mass expression $m_o(t)=\rho(t) v_o t$ is incorrect, because $\rho(t)$ is not constant. Correct expression needs integration of right part instead of multiplication by $t$: $m_o(t)=\int_0^t \rho(t) v_o\, dt$, then $\frac{dm_o}{dt}=\rho(t) v_o$ and $\frac{dm}{dt}=\frac{dm_i}{dt}-\frac{dm_o}{dt}=\rho_i v_i-\rho(t) v_o$. $\rho(t)=\frac{m(t)}{V}$, where $V$ is constant, then $\frac{dm}{dt}=\rho_i v_i -\frac{m(t)}{V}v_o$. If you use $y(t)=m(t)$ notation and put given values you obtain correct equation $y'=10-\frac{y}{20}$. Initial condition is $y(0)=m(0)=\rho(0) V=250$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thank you! Can you please explain how you came to that integral for $m_o$, without just saying that you integrated the rate of change, because then it's a chicken and egg problem in my confusion? As I wrote in the problem statement, I know that the derivative of the output mass should be that integrand, but I am looking for a way to derive that.

Comment: Let consider your formula $m_o(t)=\rho(t) v_o t$. This formula is correct for case of constant $\rho(t)$. Let consider infinitesimal ($dt\to 0$) time interval $(t;t+dt)$, for this interval $\rho(t)$ is approximately constant, then $dm_o = \rho(t) v_o\, dt$. Then one can integrate with initial condition $m_o(0)=0$ to get integral formula for $m_o(t)$ or one can just divide both parts by $dt$ to get the rate of change. This is not checken and egg problem. Both formulae are equivalent and both are results of correct use of your formula $m=\rho v t$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thanks! This is clearer now. However, I haven't seen such infinitesimal calculus formally before, where I could assign a value to $dt$ and divide by it to get different meanings of the formula, and still make it the same $dt$ used for integrals. Do you know why $m_o(t)$ is not equal to $\rho(t) v_0 t$ in general? I understand that the integral of $dm_o$ you defined will be different from the function I wrongly proposed in the answer, but I wonder if there is a more formal derivation, that I could understand now.

Comment: Another explanation. Let $m_o(t)$ is mass that was outgoing to the moment $t$. Let consider $m_o'(t)=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\frac{m_o(t+\Delta t)-m_o(t)}{\Delta t}$. Difference $m_o(t+\Delta t)-m_o(t)=<\rho(t,\Delta t)> v_o \Delta t$, where $<\rho(t,Delta t)>$ is average (in some sense) value of $\rho$ in interval $(t,t+\Delta t)$. Then $m_o'(t)=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\frac{<\rho(t,\Delta t)> v_o \Delta t}{\Delta t}=v_o \lim_{\Delta t\to 0}<\rho(t,\Delta t)>$. When $\Delta t\to 0$ variation of $\rho(t)$ tends to zero, then $<\rho(t,\Delta t)>\to \rho(t)$, then $m_o'(t)=\rho(t)v_o$.

Comment: As about why $m_o(t) \neq \rho(t) v_o t$, this question is similar to why $s(t)\neq v(t) t$ in general, where $s$ is distance, $v$ is velocity. This is because $v(t)$ does not depend on behavior in whole time interval $(0;t)$, it depends only on behavior in infinitesimal time interval $(t;t+dt)$, and $s(t)$ depends on behavior in whole time interval $(0;t)$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thank you! Saying that $m_o(t + \Delta t) - m_o(t) = \rho(t, \Delta t) v_o \Delta t$ could be grounded by a mean-value theorem, if we know that $m_o'(t) = \rho(t) v_o$, but that's something you want to prove, so it seems like a chicken and egg problem again. If you don't think it is, what is your ground because of which you know that such an average value of $\rho$ exists in that interval?

Comment: I didn't use mean-value theorem just the fact that average value must tend to instant value at time difference approaching zero. This fact follows from continuity of $\rho(t)$. $m(t)$ is continuous then $\rho(t)=\frac{m(t)}{V}$ is also continuous.

Answer (score 1):

It becomes too long for comments.

To write correct expression for $m_o'(t)$ one needs to have some basic formula.

Let use basic formula $m_o=\rho v_o t$. There is problem with direct using of this formula because this formula is incorrect for $\rho$ changing with time: at $\rho=2.5$ lb/gal system loses (hereafter we didn't considering income of salt) $\rho v_o=12.5$ lb/min of salt and at $\rho=2$ lb/gal system loses $\rho v_o=10$ lb/min of salt, then time moments are not equivalent and $m_o$ is not proportional to $t$.

Then we need somehow modify basic formula to get working for $\rho$ changing with time. Let consider infinitesimal time interval when $\rho$ can be considered as constant. Then we use the fact that basic formula works for constant $\rho$ and assume that **basic formula works for almost constant $\rho(t)$**, then during this infinitesimal time interval of duration $dt$ system will lose $dm_o=\rho(t) v_o dt$ of salt. Then there are two options: combine infinitesimal intervals from 0 to $t$ and get total $m_o$ as sum of infinitesimal increases $dm_o$, which is integral; or just divide both parts by $dt$ to get ratio of infinitesimal increases of function $dm_o$ and independent variable $dt$, which is derivative. Resulting formulae are

$$m_o(t)=m_o(0)+\int_0^t \rho(t) v_o \, dt$$
$$m_o'(t)=\rho(t) v_o$$

Another option for getting the same result is physical analysis of problem. If we assume that **$m_o'(t)$ depend only on $\rho(t)$ and $v_o$**, then we can write $m_o'(t)=f(\rho(t),v_o)$. Then we can use this equation for case of constant $\rho$, when we assume basic formula is working. Considering this case we can get $f(\rho,v_o)=\rho v_o$, then in general case $m_o'(t)=\rho(t) v_o$.

From pure mathematical point of view there is possibility that $m_o'(t)$ depend on something except $\rho(t)$ and $v_o$, for example $m_o'(t)=f(\rho(t),v_o,\rho'(t))$. In this case we cannot solve the problem, because given information is not enough to recover $f$. That's why obtaining formula $m_o'(t)=\rho(t) v_o$ is out of pure mathematics. We need to use some additional assumptions outside from mathematics. These assumptions are bold-fonted above.

Comment: Thank you, Ivan! Your answer is very helpful! I think your "basic formula works for almost constant $\rho(t)$" should probably be that the basic formula "almost works" for "almost constant $\rho(t)$" (i.e. the more constant $\rho$ is, the more the formula works). However, until now my experience with mathematics is more exact than that, so I am hoping we can get such an answer here as well. Do agree with that at least?

Comment: Reading your answer, maybe the main unknown/confusion on my side is when to treat a given variable as a derivative (e.g. as velocity, $ds/dt$), and when as the point value (e.g. as density, $m/V$), because in both cases the unit is a quotient (e.g. $m/s$ or $kg/m^3$), so the definition is not clear from the unit alone. If I would know that, then it could be natural (as I think you are suggesting) to start with $m_o'(t)=\rho(t)v_o$, but I'm still not at that level, and to me it's not clear when to take the function and when the derivative of the function. Maybe that's simpler to explain?