# Swimming pool filtering problem: Concentration as a function of time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I thought of this problem while i was helping clean up a swimming pool from algae:

Let's say we have a swimming pool with capacity $C$ $[\ell]$ and an initial algae concentration of $A_0$ $[Kg/\ell]$.

We also introduce a filter that takes water from the pool and reintroduces it back in after having filtered it, we therefore define an a-dimensional filtering coefficient $k$ (e.g. if $k = 0.8$, $80\%$ of the algae gets removed in the filter) and a pump flow rate $p$ $[\ell/s]$

We want to find the function $A(t)$ ,which defines the concentration of algae in the pool at time $t$, with $A(0) = A_0$

I know a differential equation needs to be solved in order to find $A(t)$, but admittedly i'm rusty on the subject and i don't really know how to set up the differential equation.

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722399/how-to-find-concentration-of-a-solution-differential-equation-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the total amount of algae $T(t)$ in grams and a small time interval $\Delta t$, we have
\begin{align}
T(t_0 + \Delta t) - T(t_0) &\approx -(\text{Amount of algae removed per sec}) \cdot \Delta t \\ &= -(\text{Liters filtered per sec}) \cdot (\text{Algae per liter}) \cdot (\text{filter effectiveness}) \cdot  \Delta t \\
&= -p \cdot \frac{T(t_0)}{C} \cdot k \cdot \Delta t.
\end{align}
Dividing by $\Delta t$ we see that we can model the situation with the ODE
$$
T'(t) = -\frac{p\cdot k}{C} T(t),
$$
to which you probably know the solution. (Then dividing the solution by $C$ gives the solution in terms of the algae concentration.)